# Parse.com log keeps returning string as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my cloud code below Im trying to set the variable leanBody equal to a certain string but it keeps returning a weird array [object Object].  I dont know why it is doing this.  in my efforts to debug and find where this array is being set from I have tried to(SEPARATELY):

- Set leanBody equal to an arbitrary string in the global declaration
- then i tried to set it to an arbitrary string in the varReset function
- then i even commented out leanBody = (results.get("messageBody")); in the afterSave function

still i keep getting a log saying that it equals [object Object].

```
  var leanBody = "";
  var leanSenderName = "";
  var leanSenderId = "";
  var randUsers = [];

function varReset(leanBody, leanSenderName, leanSenderId, randUsers){
   leanBody = "";
   leanSenderName = "";
   leanSenderId = "";
   randUsers = [];
   console.log("The variables were set");
}


Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Lean", function(leanBody, leanSenderName, leanSenderId, randUsers, request) {
  varReset(leanBody, leanSenderName, leanSenderId, randUsers);

  var leanQuery = new Parse.Query("Lean");
  leanQuery.first({
    success: function(leanBody, results){
      console.log("The first object was retrieved");
      console.log("leanBody = " + leanBody);
      leanBody = (results.get("messageBody"));
    }, error: function(error){
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(leanBody);` instead of concatenating with a string. This should show you what it really is.

Comment: console.log("leanBody = " , leanBody);

Comment: I tried what mafafu suggested and it appears that leanBody is what "results" should be meaning its the first object in leanQuery.  Why is it not passing the value of leanBody from the varReset function?